# flutter:future is not working ,it show me error?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

In my below code future is not working ...edited code is below ###########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

```
     void compressImage() async {
    print('startin');
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(99999999);

    Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    Im.copyResize(image, 500);

//    image.format = Im.Image.RGBA;
//    Im.Image newim = Im.remapColors(image, alpha: Im.LUMINANCE);

    var newim2 = new File('$path/img_$rand.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(image, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      file = newim2;
    });
    print('done');
  }

  void clearImage() {
    setState(() {
      file = null;
    });
  }

  void postImage() {
    setState(() {
      uploading = true;
    });
    compressImage();
    Future<String> upload = uploadImage(file).then((String data) {
      Firestore.instance.collection("Advertice").document().setData({
        "Content": discription,
        "title": title.toUpperCase(),
        "url": data,
      });
    }).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        file = null;
        uploading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}


Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile) async {
  var uuid = new Uuid().v1();
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(imageFile);
  Uri URL = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
  return URL.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: You will get the File Download URL:

```
String downloadUrl;

Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile) async {
  var uuid = new Uuid().v1();
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
  await ref.put(imageFile).onComplete.then((val) {
                val.ref.getDownloadURL().then((val) {
                  print(val);
                  downloadUrl = val; //Val here is Already String
                });
              });

  return downloadUrl;
}
```

Comment: a value type Future<Null> 'can't assigned to a variable of type StorageUploadTask.....is showing

Comment: url is print in console but not send to database ..i edit my code

Comment: downloadUrl = val; -- val here is already String don't use ' Uri downloadUrl;'
instead as i used in my Code use - String downloadUrl;

Comment: i tried that way but not geting value and now it show me ...type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'....my last edited code is edit in the this way ,,,,

Comment: I added putFile since put is deprecated. This would be: await ref.putFile(await imageFile)....

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile) async {
  var uuid = new Uuid().v1();
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
  StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await ref.putFile(image).onComplete;
  return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this and get the download url from the return value of this method.

```
Future<UploadTaskSnapshot> uploadImage(var imageFile) {
  var uuid = new Uuid().v1();
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(imageFile);
  // Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
  return uploadTask.future;
}
```

You can get the download url like this anywhere within the class:

```
String downloadUrl = uploadImage(imageFile).downloadUrl.toString();
```

Comment: The getter 'future' isn't defined for the class 'firebase_storage::StorageUploadTask'.

Comment: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'future'.

Comment: @HitanshuGogoi I am not getting any error. Could you paste the code as edit?

Comment: in my code the future is showing in red ..and in my Console is showing these error

Comment: code edited ...i actually use this code in my previous app but its not showing any error this time its show me error

Comment: @HitanshuGogoi Why are you not using the code from my answer? You cannot return a String when the return type of the function is Future<UploadTaskSnapshot>

Comment: can edit that parts...and String downloadUrl = uploadImage(imageFile).downloadUrl.toString(); no working

Comment: String downloadUrl = await uploadImage(imageFile);